# Would like to hide a filter button on a Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-chart

I have a pivot chart of a pivot table with two row fields and one column field. I would like to hide one of the row field buttons on the chart but leave the other visible to use as a filter. I see, when I right click on the button, the option to hide all axis buttons, but that removes both of them. Is there a way to only hide one? I am creating the table and chart in VBA, so if it can only be done with code that is fine.

Comment: So in my efforts with this, I have at least been able to disable the button using the following code: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).RowFields(2).EnableItemSelection = False`. The button is still visible though. Currently I am hiding it by pasting a white shape over it, but I consider this a clunky option.

Comment: It's a shame there isn't another way. I haven't found anything either. If they offered an "enable/disable" property why not a "hidden" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my efforts with this, I have at least been able to disable the button using the following code: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).RowFields(2).EnableItemSelection = False.` The button is still visible though. Currently I am hiding it by pasting a white shape over it, but I consider this a clunky option.